# FFMPEG - creating MPEG DASH stream, makes the first audio segment ever so slightly too short

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I am trying to create an MPEG DASH video stream with perfectly sync'd audio and video segments. I have already figured out the correlation of the aac smapling rate and video fps, so that shouldn't be the problem ( I am using 60 fps and 48kHz sampling rate => ideal segment size would be 0.5333..s but I scaled up to 1.6s).

The manifest file correctly notes that for video segments the timescale is 15360 and all segments are 24576 => 24576 / 15360 = 1.6. However, the first audio segment is 75776 and with a timescale of 48000 results in 75776 / 48000 = 1.5786..s and all the following are 76800 / 4800 = 1.6s.

Here is the (shortened, removed additional qualities) command I run:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 \
-preset medium -sc_threshold 0 -r 60 -keyint_min 96 -g 96 \
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-filter_complex "split[v0][v1]; \
    [v0] \
    drawtext=text='Frame %{frame_num} | PTS=%{pts\:hms}': \
    start_number=1:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75:boxborderw=32: \
    x=(w-text_w)/2: \
    y=(h-text_h)/1.5: \
    fontsize=128:fontcolor=yellow, \
    drawtext=text='256x144 | 95 kbbps | 60 fps': \
    start_number=1:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75:boxborderw=32: \
    x=(w-text_w)/2: \
    y=(h-text_h)/8: \
    fontsize=128:fontcolor=yellow, \
    scale=256x144 \
    [v0]; \
    [v1] \
    drawtext=text='Frame %{frame_num} | PTS=%{pts\:hms}': \
    start_number=1:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75:boxborderw=32: \
    x=(w-text_w)/2: \
    y=(h-text_h)/1.5: \
    fontsize=128:fontcolor=yellow, \
    drawtext=text='640x360 | 276 kbbps | 60 fps': \
    start_number=1:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.75:boxborderw=32: \
    x=(w-text_w)/2: \
    y=(h-text_h)/8: \
    fontsize=128:fontcolor=yellow, \
    scale=640x360 \
    [v1]" \
-b:v:0 95k -maxrate:0 100k -bufsize:0 150k \
-b:v:1 276k -maxrate:1 290k -bufsize:1 430k \
-c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 48000 \
-map [v0] \
-map [v1] \
-map 0:a:0 \
-init_seg_name \$RepresentationID\$/source_init.\$ext\$ \
-media_seg_name \$RepresentationID\$/source_chunk_\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$ \
-use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 \
-seg_duration 1.6 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
-f dash ./bbb/source.mpd
```

And here is the resulting manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
    type="static"
    mediaPresentationDuration="PT10M34.5S"
    maxSegmentDuration="PT1.6S"
    minBufferTime="PT3.2S">
    <ProgramInformation>
        <Title>Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version</Title>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <ServiceDescription id="0">
    </ServiceDescription>
    <Period id="0" start="PT0.0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" frameRate="60/1" maxWidth="640" maxHeight="360" par="16:9">
            <Representation id="0" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64000d" bandwidth="95000" width="256" height="144" sar="1:1">
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="15360" initialization="$RepresentationID$/source_init.m4s" media="$RepresentationID$/source_chunk_$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="0" d="24576" r="395" />
                        <S d="14848" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001f" bandwidth="276000" width="640" height="360" sar="1:1">
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="15360" initialization="$RepresentationID$/source_init.m4s" media="$RepresentationID$/source_chunk_$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="0" d="24576" r="395" />
                        <S d="14848" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet id="1" contentType="audio" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" lang="und">
            <Representation id="2" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="128000" audioSamplingRate="48000">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="48000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/source_init.m4s" media="$RepresentationID$/source_chunk_$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="0" d="75776" />
                        <S d="76800" r="394" />
                        <S d="29824" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```